# Luks volume in new PC destroyed header?

Tags: linux, raid, luks

I had my data backed up on a Luks Volume in a raid1 (2 discs in raid 1 first, Luks second)

I moved the 2 drives into a new server and they quit working. After a mild panic attack I searched for more info, and some of the sites suggested to use a Hexdump to check the content of the header.
But a lot of the sites were not super clear on where it is. Can anyone tell me if my data is recoverable or what happen?

All I did was move them into a new PC. No install. no commands, nothing weird. Inserted into computer with an existing OS and booted it.

`sudo hexdump -Cvs 0 -n 2000 /dev/sdb`

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001c0  01 00 ee fe ff ff 01 00  00 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00  |................|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200  45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54  00 00 01 00 5c 00 00 00  |EFI PART....\...|
00000210  53 16 20 86 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |S. .............|
00000220  af be c0 d1 01 00 00 00  00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000230  8e be c0 d1 01 00 00 00  e1 8a 60 b4 82 6f 50 42  |..........`..oPB|
00000240  93 ea db 27 34 ec a7 5b  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...'4..[........|
00000250  80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  86 d2 54 ab 00 00 00 00  |..........T.....|
```

raid was created with: (edited to match drive names)

`sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md5 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdp /dev/sdb`

lsblk show:

```
sdb                         8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk
sdp                         8:240   0   3.7T  0 disk
```

fdisk -l /dev/sdb

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: EFRX-68WT0N0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B4608AE1-6F82-4250-93EA-DB2734ECA75B
```

also just to be clear, I returned them to the original machine and they are still unrecognized. mdadm shows they are not raid members. even

mdadm --assemble --scan

does nothing

Comment: Could you clarify if you used a hardware or software RAID, how you configured the RAID on the new machine, also add the output of `lsblk`

Answer (score 2):

HUZZA! Figured it out!

So somehow when i put the HDD in my new PC they somehow got new mappings/blocksizes or somthing, No idea.

i went for broke, and did a

```
sudo hexdump -s 0 -n 1000000000 -C /dev/sdb | grep LUKS
```

This searches the first gigabyte for the phrase LUKS

and it found:

```
08000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 01  61 65 73 00 00 00 00 00  |LUKS....aes.....|
```

Next i created a loopback to that offset:

```
sudo losetup -o 0x08000000 -r -f /deb/sdb
```

Now listing my loopbacks, i can see:

```
sudo losetup -a
/dev/loop8: [0006]:659 (/dev/sdb), offset 134217728
```

now lets just open the mount, fingers crossed

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop8 luksrecover
```

and... It opened!

the ususal mount command and were back in busness!
def. making a backup of that headder.
ill copy off my data and reformat the drives then put it back
Still no idea why that happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your hexdump shows the block #0 (00000000 - 000001ff) and the beginning part of block #1 (00000200+).

At 000001fe, there is the value 0xaa55 (little-endian). That in block #0 would be the basic indication of a MBR partition table being present. The first (and in this case, only) primary partition entry would be at 000001be - 000001cd, i.e.:

```
000001b0  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..  .. .. .. .. .. .. 00 00  |................|
000001c0  01 00 ee fe ff ff 01 00  00 00 ff ff ff ff .. ..  |................|
```

This [would decode to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#PTE) an inactive partition of type 0xee starting at LBA 0x00000001 with a length of 0xffffffff. Since this is larger than the CHS fields can represent, the partition start/end CHS fields can be ignored.

Partition type `0xee` indicates this is a GPT *protective MBR*, so this MBR partition table should be ignored altogether and the [real GPT partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_table_header_(LBA_1)) begins at LBA #1.

Starting at 00000228 in your hex dump is the GPT header field `first usable LBA`, which has the value 0x00000000 00000800, i.e. block 2048. Multiply that by the block size of 512 bytes, and you'll get 0x100000, or 1048576, which is the typical 1MiB into the disk. That does not match the offset you found (134217728 = 128 MiB into the disk), so maybe there is some non-LUKS partition on the disk before the LUKS partition. Unfortunately the GPT partition entries are held in block #2 and subsequent blocks (if needed), so your hexdump does not allow checking for their validity.

The `last usable LBA` field in the GPT header has the value 0x01d1c0be8e = 7814037134 at offset 00000230 in your dump. That's 34 blocks less than the size of the disk reported by `fdisk`, which looks correct: at the end of the disk there is 33 blocks of space for the backup GPT header block and 32 blocks of partition entries, +1 for the fact that the block numbering starts from block #0 rather than #1.

That would seem to leave no space for the RAID metadata area outside the partitioned space.

Are you absolutely sure that the RAID was created using whole-disk devices rather than partition devices? In other words, perhaps it was something like

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md5 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdp2 /dev/sdb2
```

rather than:

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md5 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdp /dev/sdb
```

If, after creating the RAID array, you used something like `fdisk /dev/sdb` or `fdisk /dev/sdp` to partition the disks, the GPT partition table would have overwritten the RAID metadata... and after rebooting, you would have had no RAID anymore, just a plain GPT-partitioned disk (and a second disk that is now unused and rapidly getting out of sync with the first one).

There is also the possibility that [the firmware might have wiped the RAID metadata on you](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18541493) ([or here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Software-RAID-ASRock)), either back on the old system, or when you moved the disks on the new one.

Basically, the UEFI firmware on the system has no clue about Linux software RAID, but it definitely understands GPT partition tables. When the firmware sees that a disk has a GPT primary partition table at the beginning, but the backup partition table seems to be not quite at the end of the disk (because of RAID metadata stored there in metadata format 1.0 and below), some UEFI firmwares will "fix" this by incrementing the `last usable LBA` value in the primary GPT and re-writing the backup GPT to the true end of the disk, thus overwriting the RAID metadata.

This "fixing" is apparently something the UEFI firmware *should* do, according to the UEFI specification. Convenient for enterprise SAN admins resizing a LUN, but troublesome for whole-disk software RAID implementations.

Likewise, if you're using software RAID metadata format 1.1 or above (which places the RAID metadata at the beginning of the disk), the firmware will detect the *backup GPT* at the end of the disk and use it to rebuild the "missing" primary GPT... again stomping on the RAID metadata.

If you actually had a functioning software RAID at the whole-disk level, [and partitions inside the RAID](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Partitionable) then your encrypted LUKS volume would have *had to* have been something like `/dev/md/d5p2` or `/dev/md_d5p2`.

If there is now unallocated space after the primary GPT but before the beginning of the first partition, that might mean you were using RAID metadata format 1.1 or newer, and the firmware overwrote it by moving the primary GPT from a location after the RAID metadata to the true beginning of the disk.

Likewise, if your disk used to be fully occupied by partitions, but now there is about 64-128K of unallocated space after the end of the last partition, that would indicate you were using RAID metadata format 1.0 or older, and the firmware overwrote it with the backup GPT, either at your original system or when you moved the disks to the new one.

---

It seems to me that GPT has brought a few new things that anyone building a software RAID set needs to be aware of.

- Making non-partitioned RAID sets out of (pairs of) partitions seems to be fine (i.e. creating `/dev/md0` out of `/dev/sdX1` and `/dev/sdY1`, then `/dev/md1` out of `/dev/sdX2` and `/dev/sdY2`, etc.)
- When preparing to set up a whole-disk software RAID, you should take care to fully wipe both the primary and backup GPT, with `sgdisk --zap` or similar, to avoid firmware-based auto-recovery overwriting the RAID metadata immediately on next boot.
- When sub-dividing a whole-disk software RAID on UEFI systems, it might be better to use something other than GPT partitioning as the next higher layer (maybe make the whole-disk RAID array device a LVM PV?), as the firmware might detect the GPT partition table inside the RAID container and destroy the RAID metadata by attempting to "fix" the "incorrectly positioned" GPT without any knowledge of the RAID layer.
- This means using whole-disk software RAID on a UEFI-bootable system disk might not be a good idea, as the system disk basically needs to have a GPT partition table and an EFI System Partition, both of which the firmware must be able to fully understand and access.

Comment: So, i copied and pasted the original commands i used to create everything. (Well changing the drive names) Worked fine untill i moved them to the new PC, is it possible that this device changed something?
Also if you would like, i can do more hexdump to try to figure out why

Comment: After a bit of further reading, I saw mentioned that the UEFI firmware may attempt to "recover" a "corrupted" GPT and overwrite the software RAID metadata in the process, and edited my answer. Instead of hexdumping, you might look carefully at the partition table now existing on the disk, particularly at the starting point of the first partition and the ending point of the last one.